# "else" with GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, relay

### How to achieve "else" effect with GQL directives

There is a way to fetch something conditionally with [gql](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives) using `@include(if: $withFriends)`

```
query Hero($episode: Episode, $withFriends: Boolean!) {
  hero(episode: $episode) {
    name
    friends @include(if: $withFriends) {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to fetch something else if `$withFriends` is false. I can achieve it by passing additional variable `$notWithFriends`

```
query Hero($episode: Episode, $withFriends: Boolean!) {
  hero(episode: $episode) {
    name
    friends @include(if: $withFriends) {
      name
    }
    appearsIn @include(if: $notWithFriends)
  }
}
```

### Question: is it possible to avoid using additional variable?

Something like this: `@include(else: $withFriends)` or `@include(ifNot: $withFriends)` or `@include(if: !$withFriends)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `@skip` directive, which works like the opposite of `@include` -- it omits the field from the selection set if the `if` argument is `true`:

```
query Hero($episode: Episode, $withFriends: Boolean!) {
  hero(episode: $episode) {
    name
    friends @include(if: $withFriends) {
      name
    }
    appearsIn @skip(if: $withFriends)
  }
}
```

In this way, if `$withFriends` is `true`, only `name` and `friends` will be selected. If it is `false`, only `name` and `appearsIn` will be selected.